# Are there faster ways in data.table fread() to read large gz file into memory?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to read back a large gz file (about 1.5 Gb, with two columns: 1st column is numeric and 2nd column is character) named `CID-Title.gz` from my computer disk (originally, I downloaded this file from [here](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/Extras/CID-Title.gz)

I used `data.table::fread()` as below:

```
dat <- data.table::fread(file = "CID-Title.gz", showProgress = TRUE, nThread = 16)
```

How can I make this `fread` faster when reading this gz file? Or is there other trick to read the large gz file with faster speed?

Comment: How long does it take on your system, how much faster do you want/need it to go?

Comment: Thank you. I will post the time used between data.table and vroom below. But basically vroom wins in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `vroom` package (web page [here](https://vroom.r-lib.org/), CRAN page [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=vroom)). It reads to a tidyverse tibble: I don't know if there is a downstream performance penalty for converting the tibble to a data.table object.

> vroom doesn’t stop to actually read all of your data, it simply indexes where each record is located so it can be read later. The vectors returned use the Altrep framework to lazily load the data on-demand when it is accessed, so you only pay for what you use. This lazy access is done automatically, so no changes to your R data-manipulation code are needed.

> vroom also uses multiple threads for indexing, materializing non-character columns, and when writing to further improve performance.

> vroom supports reading zip, gz, bz2 and xz compressed files automatically, just pass the filename of the compressed file to vroom.

From the [vroom benchmarks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html):

[image: bar plot of vroom benchmarks]

Comment: Note mostly to myself for later. There's one missing comparison from that chart - `vroom(altrep=TRUE) - data.table` - I assume `vroom` plays nicely?

Comment: `dt <- fread(file = "CID-Title.gz", showProgress = TRUE, nThread = 25)`
# 12 min
`tb <- vroom(file = "CID-Title.gz", col_names = FALSE, num_threads = 25, altrep = TRUE)`
# 58 sec

Comment: Very strange why in this case the data.table is so slow? Maybe there are other tricks to read such a file. Hope other people can try this file I provided in my question.

Comment: People might not be in a hurry to download a 1.5Gb file and run experiments on it ... are you possibly RAM-limited?  I would also try a *smaller* number of threads - it's possible that you've gone beyond the range where parallelization is actually useful. (It's hard for me to say more because (1) I'm not actually terribly knowledgeable about parallel computation and (2) you haven't told us anything about the characteristics of your hardware ...)

Comment: (12 minutes definitely sounds like too much; other fread benchmarks such as [this one](https://jozef.io/r917-fread-comparisons/) are getting 15 Gb in 1.4 min, about 100 times as fast as your example ...)

Comment: You are right. With less cores, data.table is much faster then.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to post some timings from your system (along with a few more details about your hardware) as an answer.

Comment: Arguably, knowing the addresses of the columns is different from reading into memory

Comment: @BenBolker `st <- Sys.time()
dt <- fread(file = fpath, nThread = 5)
print(Sys.time() - st)`
# Time difference of 6.902643 mins and `st <- Sys.time()
tb <- vroom(file = fpath, num_threads = 5, col_names = FALSE, altrep = TRUE)
setDT(tb)
print(Sys.time() - st)` # Time difference of 4.099605 mins   I run it in the 16-core HPC Linux system with 240 GB memory. For vroom option, I must use additional `setDT()` to convert tibble into data.table. This time wins about 6.5 min compared with data.table. The difference is not that large. `fpath <- "./CID-Title.gz"`